# Laravel redirect to another subdomain

Tags: laravel, subdomain

I’d like to redirect my subdomain `test.example.com` to another sub-domain `www.example.com`. I added the code below in my `routes.php` but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{test}.example.com'), function() {
     Route::get('/', function($test) {
         return Redirect::to('http://www.example.com');
     });
});
```

When I type `test.example.com` in my browser I'm not being redirected to `www.example.com`. Does someone have any suggestions how I can fix this?

Comment: Can you access well your first subdomain `test.example.com` ?

Comment: yes, that works fine. It seems that I get the content which is on www.example.com, but I'm not being redirected to text.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't played with sub domain routes myself just yet but try this

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{test}.example.com', 'before' => 'tomaindomain');


Route::filter('tomaindomain', function()
{
    return Redirect::to('SomeDomain.com');
});
```

I've only applied a route filter to the entire subdomain, you could remove the wildcard or check `$test` is equal to `"test"` before redirecting. I figured you could just return a Redirect request inside an if statement from within the Route group but I haven't tested it.

Comment: thanks so much for helping. I figured out that the CNAME record that I was using in my DNS was causing this problem. I removed the CNAME and replaced it with a URL record, 301 permanently moved, and it looks like it is now doing redirecting to the right subdomain.

Comment: Oh dear! Be sure to answer your own question just so people searching for a similar answer can also follow your tracks if need be.

Comment: Thanks, I'll answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I had a problem with the settings of my DNS server. I was using a CNAME record for my subdomain "test.example.com" instead of using a URL record, 301 permanently moved. So, I removed my CNAME record and replaced it with a URL record, and everything seems now to be working fine. Thanks @everon and @Set Kyar Wa Lar for helping